# javascript/jquery: focus() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, roundcube

I want to focus a special id (in roundcube) by a keyboard shortcut. The html is

```
   ... 
   <div id="mainscreen">
    <div id="messagetoolbar" class="toolbar">
    <div id="mailview-left" style="width: 220px;">
    <div id="mailview-right" style="left: 232px;">
    ...
```

I tried the following:

```
 // Strg + Tab, um in Nachrichtenbereich zu kommen
 ...
 else if (event.keyCode == 9 && event.ctrlKey) {
 alert("taste erkannt");
 //document.getElementById("messagetoolbar").focus();
 //$("#messagetoolbar").focus();
 setTimeout(function() { $('#messagetoolbar').focus(); alert("zeit"); }, 3000);
 }
 ...
```

The first alert and the second alert is shown but no focus on id messagetoolbar. Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you very much.

**Edit:** I think I should describe it better: I want to mark the first line/email in the email-inbox in roundcube. The inbox is a table with a tr-tag...when I try your solution the first line is dotted, too, but with enter I can't open the mail and with other keys I can't MARK the first line/mail... I think I have to "simulate a left-klick" to get the first line marked...?
Now I tried to use jquery's .trigger. The html of the inbox-Table is

```
 <table id="messagelist" class="records-table messagelist sortheader fixedheader">
  <thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="rcmrow27428" class="message">
         <td class="threads"></td>
         <td class="date">16.04.2014 13:41</td>
         <td class="fromto">
 ...
```

I tried to use...

```
 $('#messagelist tr').eq(1).addClass('message selected focused').removeClass('unfocused').trigger("click");
```

...but it doesn't work: It adds an removes the classes but doesn't really focus the line  :-( With "buttons" it works.

**EDIT AGAIN:** I think the file list.js of roundcube is important for that question. There I found the following:

```
/**
 * Set focus to the list
 */
focus: function(e)
{
  var n, id;
  this.focused = true;

  for (n in this.selection) {
    id = this.selection[n];
    if (this.rows[id] && this.rows[id].obj) {
      $(this.rows[id].obj).addClass('selected').removeClass('unfocused');
    }
  }

  // Un-focus already focused elements (#1487123, #1487316, #1488600, #1488620)
  // It looks that window.focus() does the job for all browsers, but not Firefox (#1489058)
  $('iframe,:focus:not(body)').blur();
  window.focus();

  if (e || (e = window.event))
    rcube_event.cancel(e);
},
```

Does anybody know how to modify or use referring to my question? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add `tabindex=0` attribute to the div you want to foucs and you will be able to set focus on the div using .focus()

Comment: With tabindex=0 it works in so far, that I get a dotted line around the div/element. With buttons (equipped with a "rcmail-command"/an onclick-command) it works: After focussed I can press enter and then the command is executed.

Comment: But originally I want to mark the first line/email in the email-inbox in roundcube. The inbox is a table with <tr>...when I try your solution the first line is dotted, too, but with enter I can't open the mail and with other keys I can't MARK the first line/mail... I think I have to simulate a left-klick to get the first line marked..?

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** focus controls like `div`, `span` etc. You can move to that `div` if required using [book marks](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aabg020899a.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to highlight the div then you can use the jquery and following code to give highlight effect.

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Note that this requires jQuery UI, and not just jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

I've read a few times now, that one can't focus table rows but only can focus elements, which accepts input by the user. Otherwise I think there must be a way to simulate a click on a table row by jquery/javascript!  I tried the following:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  ...
  else if (event.keyCode == 9 && event.ctrlKey) {
   $('#messagelist tr').on('click', function () {
    alert('I was clicked');
    });
    $('#messagelist tr').eq(1).click();
  }
... 
}
```

The alert is shown! But the row isn't "marked"!?